# contrib.learn.estimator() for tensorflow0.12

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I am using contrib.learn.estimator to predict in tensorflow0.12 environment.

```
#1. Use a regression Estimator, set n_classes to 0    
model = skflow.SKCompat(skflow.Estimator(model_fn=lstm_model, model_dir=LOG_DIR))

#2. create a lstm instance and validation monitor
validation_monitor = skflow.monitors.ValidationMonitor(X, y,
                                                     every_n_steps=steps,
                                                     early_stopping_rounds=1000)

#3. fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, monitors=[validation_monitor], steps=steps)

#4. Predict
y_train_predicted = model.predict(X_train)
```

and the LSTM model is

```
def lstm_model(X, y):
X = tf.reshape(X, [-1, n_steps, n_input])   #batch_size,n_steps,n_input
#permute n_steps and batch_size
X = tf.transpose(X, [1, 0, 2])
#Reshape to prepare input to hidden activation
X = tf.reshape(X, [-1, n_input])            #n_steps*batch_size, n_input
#Split data because rnn cell needs a list of inputs for the RNN inner loop
X = tf.split(0, n_steps, X)                 #n_steps*(batch_size, n_input)

init = tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev = 0.05)
lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(hidden, initializer = init, state_is_tuple = True)


output, _ = tf.nn.rnn(lstm_cell, X, dtype = tf.float32)

y = tf.convert_to_tensor(y)

return skflow.models.linear_regression(output[0], y)
```

The error reports

```
 File "/home/lstm.py", line 182, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, monitors=[validation_monitor], steps=steps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 1131, in fit
    max_steps=max_steps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 699, in _train_model
    train_ops = self._get_train_ops(features, labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 1052, in _get_train_ops
    return self._call_model_fn(features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 1030, in _call_model_fn
    raise ValueError('Unrecognized value returned by model_fn, '
ValueError: Unrecognized value returned by model_fn, please return ModelFnOps."
```

if I modify the model line as

```
model = skflow.SKCompat(skflow.Estimator(model_fn=lstm_model(X, y), model_dir=LOG_DIR))
```

It still reports error:

```
  File "/home/lstm.py", line 175, in <module>
    model = skflow.SKCompat(skflow.Estimator(model_fn=lstm_model(X, y), model_dir=LOG_DIR))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 990, in __init__
    if params is None and 'params' in model_fn_args:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I am confused with the contrib.learn.estimator() for tensorflow 0.12. Could anyone help me correct the code and teach me on Estimate? Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model_fn argument shall not be the return of ModelFnOps(). A mamual model_fn name is required:

```
def model_fn(features, targets, mode):
    '''Implement of model_fn API.

    # Logic to do the following:
    # 1. Configure the model via TensorFlow operations
    # 2. Define the loss function for training/evaluation
    # 3. Define the training operation/optimizer
    # 4. Generate predictions
    # 5. Return predictions/loss/train_op/eval_metric_ops in ModelFnOps object

    Args:
        features: Inputs data for the model.
        targets: Expected outputs of the model namely labels.
        mode: learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN/EVAL/INFER

    Returns:
        ModelFnOps object.
    '''
```

And then when you define an Estimator:

```
model = SKCompat(learn.Estimator(
    model_fn=model_fn,
    model_dir='path/to/your/model'
))
```